# What's the font of the Kubernetes logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, typography, font-identification

Does anyone know what the font of the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) logo (a container orchestration system) is?

[image]

[WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) yielded no results for it, it's not mentioned in the [WhatTheFont Forum](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/?q=kubernetes).

If it's not an official font, does anyone know a font looking similar to this one?

Further official versions of the logo are [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/logo).

Answer (score 6):

Some research in the [GitHub comments](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23071#issue-63125191) and on Google Fonts revealed that the font actually is **[Ubuntu](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu)** in the **Bold 700** style:

[image]